# Can't uninstall Cyanogenmod11 themes

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, themes

Recently I installed a number of Cyanogenmod11 Themes from the Android Market. Now I want to uninstall some of then But whenever I try to uninstall it my phone soft reboots. And the theme is still in the phone.
The phone I'm using is Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini GT-i8190 running CyanogenMod11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Just press and hold the power button; once the power menu appears, tap and hold the reboot button and press OK to reboot in safe mode. Now you should be able to uninstall the themes without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using those themes, just switch to the default theme and try uninstalling them. That usually works.

Comment: I did that before but all in vain. Whenever I click that uninstall button it soft reboots.

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode, all apps were crashing including settings. Therefore i rebooted the phone and uninstalled the installed themes from Settings -> Apps -> Downloaded apps. Done!